# Term for meeting top level criteria by meeting all lower level criteria

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests

I'm trying to find the word for meeting a summary-level (top level) requirement/criteria, by meeting all lower level criteria.

For example, assume the only requirements for being a car were 1) 4+ wheels, 2) has an engine, and 3) can carry one or more passengers. What I would like to say is that "By meeting the three sub-criteria, that thing can be classified as a car _________ ". The closest I can think is "by default" or "by proxy", but neither really seem to fit.

EDIT:
After asking this question, I think the phrase is "by virtue of", as in "This thing can be classified as a car *by virtue of* satisfying the three sub-criteria". Thoughts?

Comment: _By definition_? (It doesn't mean exactly what you say, but it means that the vehicle satisfies all your conditions for 'being a car'.)

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks, that's a great suggestion.

Comment: _Technically_ could work also. "By meeting the three sub-criteria, that thing can _technically_ be classified as a car."

Comment: It can be classified as a car, because it satisfies all the required elements.  If "elements" sounds too legalistic, you could replace it with "criteria."  By the way, "criteria" is fine -- you don't need "sub-criteria."